# how to rename column name without hard coding in SQL display

Tags: sql

Currently if I want to rename the column name to something else, I would do

```
Select column as "what I want to name it" 
from table1
```

However, I don't want to hard code the column name so I tried to set a variable

```
set @var = "some name"
select column as @var 
from table1
```

but this is giving me syntax error, what am I doing wrong? All help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for that. How to do this strongly depends on the DB engine you use.

Comment: Why do you not want the column to be hard coded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL processor just doesn't work that way. Variable evaluation happens within expressions; it can't be used for structuring the output.

You can use dynamic SQL, if you really have to, but it's like killing a fly with a rusty chainsaw that has no guard on its blade.  Better to not do this in the SQL.

As @juergend said in a comment, the form of the dynamic SQL depends on what SQL engine you are using: Oracle, SQL Server, mySQL, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here how in SQL Server with dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @columnName VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(100)

SET @columnName = 'Column1'

SET @sql = 'SELECT 1 AS ' + @columnName

EXEC (@sql)
```